# Is there a justification for rejecting email addresses without dots in the mailbox name?

Tags: email

By this, I mean rejecting `foo@example.com` and insisting on `foo.bar@example.com` as a means of communicating with me (and in one case, as a login).

A few years ago, the French social security administration (URSSAF) applied this policy and last week the postal service (laposte.fr).

I understand that Gmail simply ignores dots in the mailbox name which potentially adds complexity to account handling code if the email address is used as a login, as it is for laposte.fr.

Is there a security-related reason for this rule?

Comment: What do you mean by rejecting it.  None of my email addresses have ever had a fullstop in them.

Comment: @RohitGupta - I am not allowed to use an address without a dot as my email address on their site. I'll edit the question. Like you, I never had a dot in my address from choice.

Comment: Is there any guidance online that they post about this? Something we can assess instead of your summary of the situation?

Comment: No. For the URSSAF, I had a message each time I logged in to say that my email was invalid, but they managed to send me mails; it was only when I wanted to use their messaging system that I had to change the mail.
For La Poste, one uses the email to login and after entering the existing mail and password, there was a message asking me to enter a new email address, to which they sent a confirmation (not secure!).

Comment: This is still unclear. They specifically said that the email address needed to have a period? What was the message? All we're getting is your summary of your memory of the situation. There might be other relevant details that you don't include.

Comment: @schroeder. No, the two systems concerned just said that the address which I had been using for more than a year in each case was now invalid. I did try another working address without a dot (also rejected) before testing the hypothesis that the dot was the problem.
For me, my hypothesis is proven. I was unaware of the Gmail behaviour before searching to see if there was un urban myth or a real reason behind the change.

Comment: So, it's a guess that it's the dot ... It would be very helpful if you provided the actual message or more valid proof that the dot is the material factor.

Answer (score 2):

There is no *technical* reason for this. A `.` is just a character.

There *could* be a reason to require a full name, however. But that's not a technical nor a security reason but an identity reason.